# Como recibir alertas tras actualizaciones de PHP, MySQL y demás?

Tags: php, mysql

tras la reciente salida de php 7.0.12 que la he visto por casualidad me surge la duda de si hay algún servicio que te pueda enviar un mail cuando se lance una nueva actualización de un servicio como php, mysql y demás.

Para un programador solitario, que todo se lo guisa y todo se lo come, es difícil estar al día de cosas de sistemas (aunque realmente es de programación, porque es estar al día de los cambios de programación de los proyectos de PHP y de MySQL)

Comment: Entra en las páginas oficiales a ver si hay algún servicio de suscripción de noticias

Comment: estos tipos de preguntas no son adecuados en SO... En esta pagina http://www.phpweekly.com/ recibirás newsletters con todos los temas relacionado de php

Comment: Tendrías que subscrbirte en alguna newsletter, seguir los proyectos en las redes sociales o visitar las páginas, pero no hay ningún servicio que te informe acerca de la nueva versión, aunque si no es así corregirme porque me interesaría también.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si todos los proyectos que quieres "vigilar" están en github puedes suscribirte por Atom a la publicación de nuevos `Releases`.

Basta con agregar `.atom` a la URL de la pestaña de `Releases` del proyecto y ahí tienes lo que debes agregar a tu cliente de noticias.

Ejemplos:

- PHP: https://github.com/php/php-src/releases.atom
- MySQL Server: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/releases.atom

Si no están en github debes buscar la manera específica que proporcione ese proyecto o plataforma para notificar a administradores/desarrolladores la salida de una nueva versión: listas de distribución, avisos por correo integrados, RSS, etc.

Comment: Gracias por la información, es muy util!